# Is it necessary to have write "var i=0" in a for loop instead of just i=0? What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

I'm wondering why we write this:

```
for (var i=0; i<11 ; i++){
  console.log("The number is "+i)
}
```

Instead of just this:

```
for (i=0; i<11 ; i++){
  console.log("The number is "+i)
}
```

Is the "var i" necessary? If not, why do we put it? Both code blocks return the same thing and work.

Comment: *"Is the "var i" necessary?"* Yes. Without it, your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- it's creating a **global** variable called `i`. This was arguably a mistake in the definition of JavaScript; one that's been corrected by strict mode, where assigning to an undeclared variable is the error it always should have been.

Comment: Not a very good duplicate. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: I misunderstood your comment.